# Hold modifier keys

Tags: autohotkey

### 1. Briefly

I don't understand, how I can make these actions:

- hold modifier keys,
- print some symbols, when modifier keys hold,
- drop modifier keys.

I need it, because I use [**Clipjump**](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/39662/23324).

---

### 2. Expected behavior

Simply example:

[image: Expected]

<kbd>Ctrl Down</kbd> → <kbd>V</kbd> → <kbd>V</kbd> → <kbd>Ctrl Up</kbd>.

---

### 3. Actual behavior

Part of my script:

```autohotkey
#t::
Send, {LCtrl Down}
Sleep, 1000
Send, {V}
Sleep, 1000
Send, {V}
Sleep, 1000
Send, {LCtrl Up}
return
```

[image: Actual]

<kbd>Ctrl Down</kbd> → <kbd>V</kbd> → <kbd>Ctrl Up</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl Down</kbd> → <kbd>V</kbd> → <kbd>Ctrl Up</kbd>.

---

### 4. Did not help

1. In Google, I write queries, for example, `autohotkey hold modifier keys`, `autohotkey hold ctrl`, but I can get no answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

You might try the different send modes.  `SendInput` for example.  You might use a plain "`v`" (instead of a shifted - capital - "V").  You might add a key multiplier  `{key #}` instead of repeating.

```
#t::
  SendInput, {LCtrl Down}
  Sleep, 1000
  SendInput, v
  Sleep, 1000
  SendInput, v
  Sleep, 1000
  SendInput, {LCtrl Up}
return
```

Or Better yet:

```
#t::
  SendInput, {LCtrl Down}
  Sleep, 1000
  SendInput, {v 2}
  Sleep, 1000
  SendInput, {LCtrl Up}
return
```

or even:

```
#t::
  SendInput, {LCtrl Down}{v 2}{LCtrl Up}
return
```

EDITed per comment:  You might also try just using the ordinary ahk facility with modifiers, and try it under the different send modes, too:

```
#t::
  Send, ^{v 2}
return
```

Hth,

Comment: You test your scripts? I get same result, as in `Actual behavior` section, not in `Expected behavior` section. Thanks.

Comment: Yup, tested and confirmed: works on desktop, within explorer and MS Office programs, etc. (but hard to tell difference between `^{v 2}` and `^v^v`.  And I don't use "clipjump," so ymmv.  But wait, did you even try `SendPlay`, too?  Or reverting back to `SendEvent` with an appropriate `SetKeyDelay`?  The "Help" on this stuff is pretty good.  Start here:  https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm

Comment: Actually, writing that comment leads me to ask why you don't just do a `^{v 2}`?  Why do you think you need to expressly hold the left alt key and then release it?  See my additional edit, above.